# Diff command failing when executed from jenkins shell script

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, scripting, diff

The diff command I execute is simple, but failing when given from excecute shell script of jenkins.

```
echo 'diff Delta_changes_current.txt Delta_changes_previous.txt >> PR.DELTA.FILES'
chmod 777 delta.sh
. ./delta.sh
diff Delta_changes_current.txt Delta_changes_previous.txt
```

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

there is not even an error to find out what is the issue with this.

When I am running the same from server directly the command is giving result.

can someone plz help me find what needs to be done

..

The above snippet is from logs.
Let me paste the logs by running the command only ..

```
+ diff Delta_changes_current.txt Delta_changes_previous.txt
1,4c1
< ################################# Delta_Changes_currect file for Junit##########
< 
< /OptionlessVDDSController.java
< /OptionlessVDDSControllerTest_.java
\ No newline at end of file
---
> /OracleBroker.java
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Its printing output and failing immediately

Comment: With the additional information, I believe @user1934428 identified the real root cause, the exit status of the `diff` cmd. When an exit cide from a shell is not specified, it returns the last cmd result. You could add a line as noted to override.

Answer (score 2):

According to the *diff* man-page:

_ Exit status is 0 if inputs are the same, 1 if different, 2 if trouble._

If the files are different, `diff` sets exit status 1. Jenkins treats an execution step as failed, if it returns with an exit status different from 0.

You could add one more command to catch this case:

```
(( $? < 2 )) && true # Convert status 1 to 0
```

Comment: This really saved me a lot of time. It took this much to understand that diff command is returning exit code that causing failure. Thanks alot

Comment: @sravanisrinija Be careful - there are several commands, which can return non-zero exit code, even they don't _fail_ in the intuitive sense. `grep` is another common one.

Comment: yeah.. true. I got to use grep command @ number of places in the script. My script keep on failing whenever it encountered grep,.. that too only when ran from Jenkins. Its fine from direct server. :(

Comment: @sravanisrinija : When I used shell scripting (in my case zsh) under Jenkins, I did not define each command as a separate jenkins step, but wrote whole scripts in which I have control over the overall exit code. I don't need Jenkins to "look" at every single command being executed.